# Executing stored procedure in Nodejs mysql safely

Tags: mysql, node.js

Is there a way to execute stored procedure using Nodejs mysql pool so that it is safe from sql injection?

I have a stored procedure that I am calling like this:

```
rows = await pool.query(`Call users_getInfoByNameAndHash('${name}','${hash}')`)
rows = rows[0]
```

However, if try to login with username `Dave's` then I want it to execute the query with that string but I get:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'Dave'

Edit 1 :

Here is my code for stored procedure:

```
  create procedure users_getInfoByNameAndHash
    (
        IN name varchar(255), 
        IN pass varchar(255)
    )
    BEGIN
        Select * from users 
        where userName = name 
        and

 password = pass;
END
```

Edit2 :

I have experience using MSSQL with Nodejs which allows us to do:

```
 let result = await rows.request()
               .input('userName', sql.VarChar(50), name)
               .input('password', sql.VarChar(70), hash)
               .execute('usp_web_verifyWebUser')
```

I have not found anything like this for mysql.

Comment: is there a good cause why you didn't post the code of the procedure?

Comment: @nbk I have added the code for stored procedure

Comment: @RiggsFolly name variable is obtained from username field directly. This is Nodejs

Comment: If you are HASHing the password correctly, it should NOT be possible to do what you are doing. If you are using MD5 or SHA1 then it may work but it is not secure

Comment: Yes, it is not possible to inclide `'` in a hash field. Therefore I am trying to break my code using the username field which is not hashed. If I include `'` in username it things it is the end of the query, which is not true

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procecure works, if the text is only text.

So use prepared statementst instead

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `users_getInfoByNameAndHash`(
        IN name varchar(255), 
        IN pass varchar(255)
    )
BEGIN
    SET @name = name;
    SET @pass = pass;
   SET @sql =     "Select * from users 
        where userName = ? 
            and
        password = ?;";
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @name,@pass;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```